# Move to another View in DojoMobile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, dojox.mobile

i am developing a simple Hybrid application in IBM Worklight using DOJO.I have a Login Page and a Welcome Page. Once i press the login button it will go to function to check whether credentials are correct,if it is correct i want to mo to Welcome Page.

My code..
HTML

```
...
..
<button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id="loginBtn"
            style="margin-left: 50%; margin-top: 3%"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Login', onClick:function(e){loginCheck();}"></button>
...
..
```

.JS

.
..
function loginCheck()
{
    var username = uname.value;
    var password = pass.value;

```
if(username == "admin" && password == "admin")
    {
      //Move to another view
    }
else
    {
        alert("Incorrect Username or Password");
    }
```

}
..
..

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

I use this code and it works

```
var w = dijit.byId('currentView');
w.performTransition('newView',1,"slide",null); //or #newView
```

Don't use alert, use this :

```
WL.SimpleDialog.show(
"My Title", "My Text", 
[{text: "First Button", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("First button pressed"); }
}]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the performTransition method, see http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojox/mobile/View

Hope this helps,
Damien